# Make a git alias to remove all local merged branches

Tags: git

I have a command to delete local copies of branches that have been merged into develop:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/ | grep -v develop | xargs -L1 -I '{}' sh -c "git merge-base --is-ancestor {} develop && git branch -d {}"
```

I'd like to add an alias to my `.gitconfig` but I cannot get one to work - I think I'm messing up the escaping.  How can I get this command working, or a command that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: Can you get the non merged branches into develop easier just doing a git branch --no-merged develop? cause it looks like the for-each-ref also emits the tags as well

Comment: For some reason that listing I get from both doesn't match.  The listing I get using the ancestor check is more accurate and catches branches `git branch` doesn't catch (which I also verified are merged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding how to create an alias for a compound command or script, this should do:

```
[alias]
  branch-clear = !git for-each-ref ... | ...
```

Or via a function:

```
[alias]
  branch-clear = "!f() { git for-each-ref ... | ...; }; f"
```

Comment: I have used these before, but I cannot get them to work with the command I have.  It seems to break when I get to the `"` or maybe just `sh -c` for xargs.

Comment: Looks like there's something about `"`.  I was able to use the format of the first command using single `'`s to get something working.  Editing the answer above with what I have.